# Trouble inserting html form data into phpmyadmin database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I'm having trouble inserting form data into my database. It connects successfully to the database, but the data just doesn't get inserted into my MySQL database. Hope you can help! Thank you in advance!

This is the form code:

```
<form id="score" method="post" action="process.php">
 <fieldset>
        <div class="box1">
    <legend>Your details</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <label for=name>Name</label>
            <input id=name name=name type=text placeholder="First and last name" required autofocus>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for=email>Email</label>
            <input id=email name=email type=email placeholder="example@domain.com" required>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for=phone>Phone (country code if overseas)</label>
            <input id=phone name=phone type=tel placeholder="Eg. +447500000000" required>
        </li>
    </ol>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset style="border: none;">
    <button type=submit>Continue</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

This is the php code (filename process.php):

```
<?php
if( $_POST )
{
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","database_user","password");

if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("database_name", $con);


$insert_query = "insert into feedback(
                name,
                phone,
                email
                    ) values (
            ".$_POST['name'].",
            ".$_POST['phone'].",
            ".$_POST['email'].")";

($insert_query);

echo "<h2>Thank you for your feedback!</h2>";

mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: mysql_query($insert_query)

Comment: ***NOTE:*** You should avoid the `mysql_*` api as it is depreciated. You should instead be looking at implementing your code with [**`PDO`**](http://www.php.net//manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [**`MySQLi`**](http://www.php.net//manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: Also, if you are using this code in production it is a good practice to filter the data which user has posted. Use mysql_real_escape_string function. before putting it in a query.

Comment: thanks for the tip! will use it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
<?php
if( $_POST )
{
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","database_user","password");

if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("database_name", $con);


$insert_query = "insert into feedback(
                name,
                phone,
                email
                    ) values (
            '".$_POST['name']."',
            '".$_POST['phone']."',
            '".$_POST['email']."')";

mysql_query($insert_query);

echo "<h2>Thank you for your feedback!</h2>";

mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```

mysql_query() Is missing.

Also close the query variables with ''. Since they're strings you need to have them with that or else will fail.

Cheers

Comment: this really worked! thank you Daniel! you sure took my panic away lol. i wish there was a way to repay this awesome help!

Comment: No problem m8 ;) anytime

Answer (score 2):

You have missed `mysql_query` function :

Use this way:

```
$retval = mysql_query( $insert_query, $con );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Reference [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-insert-query.htm)

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query()` is missing. Replace

```
($insert_query);
```

with

```
mysql_query($insert_query);
```

Comment: thanks for bothering to reply! will remember the tip! :)